# List View Threshold Daily Window Message

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

SharePoint 2010 farm.

Yesterday we enabled the List View Threshold (LVT) daily window for large queries to be completed during a specific time of day, however, we are not seeing the expected error when attempting to perform an operation outside the daily window.

**What we are seeing:**

[image]

**What we are expecting to see (similar to):**

[image]

The error display/design is unimportant. The TEXT in the error is what we are concerned with. We were expecting to see the times of the daily window so that customers know when operations can be done.

**Have we missed something?** We thought it would be as simple as ticking the box in Central Administration and setting our window. It all enabled correctly, but the error text for users is not showing as we'd have expected.

Comment: it may help you https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45127/no-matter-what-i-do-i-get-that-damnable-exceed-list-view-threshold-error-message

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't provide anything related to this particular situation. We're getting the error - which is what we want - but it's not displaying that a daily window exists (like my second image). It is this text I'm trying to work out why it's not being shown even though the option is enabled and configured correctly in Central Admin for the web app. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

Per my test in my SharePoint 2010, I create a list which list items are more than 5000. And I enable the “Daily Time Window for Large Queries”. It will not display the message in the list as in your second picture.

If I query the list during the time which is set in the “Daily Time Window for Large Queries”, the list will display all items.

If I query the list not during the time which is set in the “Daily Time Window for Large Queries”, the list will only display the newest 1000 items and show the message “Displaying only the newest results below. To view all results, narrow your query by adding a filter.”.

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Check if the time is set correctly in “Daily Time Window for Large Queries” in the web application.
2. Check if “Daily Time Window for Large Queries” can work in another web application.

More reference:

[SharePoint 2010 Daily Time Window for Large Queries.](https://blog.sprider.org/2013/02/01/sharepoint-2010-daily-time-window-for-large-queries/)